# Get-Content from file with -ReadCount and Select -Skip in powershell is not outputting expected result

Tags: powershell, powershell-3.0

**Background**

I am constructing a file output from a mixture of static content, dynamic content, and another files content but some of the operation doesn't output content as I expect it to.

The static content is the text `@LANGUAGE\r\nENGLISH\r\n\r\n@FIELDS`, then I am appending the first header line of some input CSV file, then the text `\r\n@$set_name`, and finally every line of the input CSV file after the first line.

**Powershell code**

```bsh
    $set_name = "ITEM_SET"
    $inputCSVFile = "C:\temp\in\$set_name.csv"
    $outputTXTFile = "C:\temp\out\$set_name.txt"
    $staticContent = "@LANGUAGE`r`nENGLISH`r`n`r`n@FIELDS"
    $dynamicContent = "`r`n@$set_name"

    # output content to file
    $staticContent | Out-File $outputTXTFile
    Get-Content $inputCSVFile | Select -First 1 | Out-File $outputTXTFile -Append
    $dynamicContent | Out-File $outputTXTFile -Append
    # content from the next line is not appearing in the output file
    Get-Content $inputCSVFile -ReadCount 1000 | Select -Skip 1 | Out-File $outputTXTFile -Append
```

**Result**

The output file has the `@LANGUAGE...` heading content, the 1st line of the CSV file with the field headings `A1A_A1,A1A_A2,A1A_A3,A1A_N,A2A_A1,...` and the line with dynamic content `@ITEM_SET`, but I'm missing the data from the rest of the input CSV file `0,0,0,1,0,...`.

**Other Information**

The input CSV files range from a couple of lines to thousands of lines.
I've tried removing the last `Out-File` from the end of the pipeline on the offending line of the script and the console output is as expected.
I've tried removing the `Select -Skip 1` from the middle of the pipeline on the offending line of the script and the file contents is output as expected.
I've tried removing the `-ReadCount 1000` from the `Get-Content` cmdlet on the offending line of the script and the file contents is output as expected.

**Question**

Why can I not have all three components of that line of scripting and get the output I expect?

Comment: Can you highlight what output of *offending line* are you expecting? I expecting, it would take content of `$inputCSVFile` skip first 1000 lines and append rest of them to `$outputTXTFile`. Do you expect the same or something else?

Comment: I think you want the `TotalCount` parameter instead if the `ReadCount`. Try `Get-Content $inputCSVFile -TotalCount 1000 | Select-Object -Skip 1 | Out-File $outputTXTFile -Append`

Comment: As @PetSerAl pointed out `-ReadCount 1000` sends lines in batches of 1000 down the pipeline and `Select-Object` just skips the first batch...

Comment: Note that outfile encodes in unicode and set-content encodes in ansi.  Excel seems to like ansi a little better.

Comment: @LotPings this looks to me a reasonable explanation.

Comment: @js2010 noted. My target application is not using excel for the production of the input CSV or consumption of the output text file.